# Java - when to define system properties and for what reasons?

Tags: java, properties, system

This is a simple question, but may be subjective, so I would like some opinions.

I am designing a plugin-oriented project and I have a plugin that requires its own configuration file.  Without modifying the core API to accommodate for the third party configuration file, would it be acceptable for the user to provide a VM argument that points to the file, or is there a better way?

Example:

```
-Dcom.unidentified.project.plugin.MyPlugin.configFile="config/Config.xml"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who is your user.If the user is a technician for example it is probably ok.
If it is a normal user then IMO it is not a good idea.User's don't like to know such details and don't actually understand what they are doing ("what the heck is a VM argument?")
I would suggest that you have a predefined folder for your configuration and just publish that to the user. Then you just search that folder.
For example you could have just a `config` folder that contains all your configuration files e.g. in the user dir or the same dir as your application and the user is aware of this.
Then you search for the `Config.xml` or any other configuration file there

Answer (score 0):

I use a multiple approach:

1. Check VM argument
2. Check command line (not applicable here)
3. check ~/.myapp (yes it can be done on Windows using env variables)
4. Pull default from application start directory

The first one I find I take. I tend to only use the VM approach locally to override the normal functionality in development. Problem is even I forget then when I have to set up a new environment.